# How do you thank somebody for doing two things in Keigo?

Tags: keigo, business-japanese

I often run into situations where I have to thank somebody for doing two things in business emails. The sentence would essentially be:

> “Thank for doing A and B.”

I am thinking something around the lines of :

> “Aをさせていただき、Bをしていただきありがとうございました。”

A more concrete example:

> “Thank you for meeting with me and updating the schedule.” 
> お話しをさせていただき、日程を調整いただきありがとうございました。

The redundant use of Itadaki makes me feel uneasy and seems unnatural.
Any thoughts on this are much appreciated.

Comment: 「〜させていただく」 is humble for them allowing *you* to do something, not them doing something.

Comment: It's also definitely a thing to __not__ combine multiple expressions of gratitude into one sentence, so as to let each one stand on its own.

Answer (score 2):

First, let's start with your example sentences, because you aren't saying what you think you are saying...

> Aをさせていただき、Bをしていただきありがとうございました。

Loosely translates to:

> Thank you for letting *me* do A, and thank you for doing B.

As has been pointed out in one of the comments below your post, using the causative form + itadaku results in a 'letting (speaker) verb' construction.  Here's why, the causative form of the verb (～させる) is a form for either 'letting' or 'making' someone verb.  いただく is a verb for the speaker to receive something from someone else.  When you say ～させていただく, you are literally receiving of someone letting the *speaker* (verb).

This is not the case for ～していただく which is where the *speaker* receives of the *other* person verbing.

There are a few cases where the causative form *can* be used, like the verb 話す.  However, in that case, you are still humbly receiving of their letting you talk (to/with them).  The only reason this can work is because 話す implies speaking with the other person.  In cases of using keigo, you can also use verbs in which someone else gives to the speaker, like くださる.

You are right to point out that it is repetitive, because it is.  That's just how keigo can go sometimes.

You can link the two different ideas/phrases by using the て conjugation.  Another alternative is to use some other conjunctive form, and then using そして or また for the next idea.  Also, because this is keigo, it isn't a bad idea to make sure that you acknowledge the time that the spent doing that thing for you.

After talking briefly with some Japanese friends そして is not as common as また.  Also, their examples all showed that いただく and くださる are repeated for each of the tasks being performed. (Thanks @Chocolate!)

> Aをしてくださり、また、Bもして くださって/くださいまして、ありがとうございました。
>   Thank you for doing A and B.

If you were a business executive (CEO or vice president level) meeting with regular staff, you may hear くれる.  Neglecting this edge case, I would always recommend using the honorific in keigo.

---

As has been noted by others, you may not want to combine two things into one sentence when thanking.  Keigo is round about enough that giving each thing its own sentence and recognition is in itself part of the formality.  That being said, if I were to combine the actions in your example sentence, I would say the following (with special recognition from those that have helped me reach this conclusion):

> Thank you for meeting with me and updating the schedule.
>   お忙しい中お時間を [頂]{いただ}き/[頂戴]{ちょうだい}し、また、日程調整もしていただきまして、（誠に）ありがとうございました。

Comment: 「させていただく」 and 「していただく」 do not both translate to “let me do.” I believe the phrase in the question carries the meaning intended. “Thank for letting me talk to you and adjusting the schedule for me.” I do agree though that そしてand separating the two makes more sense. 「お話しさせて頂きありがとうございます。そして、日程を調整して頂きありがとうございます。」

Comment: @LangWanderer  I have tried to address this in my newly revised edits.

Answer (score -1):

> “Thank for doing A and B.”

- AもBもなさっていただき、誠にありがとうございました。

「なさる」 is the sonkeigo of する。And 「いただく」 is the kenjyougo of もらう, so that doubles-up on the 敬語。And then, I think it is grammatically correct, but sounds sort of funny / quirky to add in a "つつしむ", which makes it sort of sounds like you are rebuking yourself for even having asked him / her for having done anything on your behalf. But, I'd not add that extra in a formal email. Just in a very casual conversation, especially if you've insisted you have poor Japanese skills:

- AもBもなさっていただき、つつしんで誠にありがとうございました。

> “Thank you for meeting with me and updating the schedule.”

- お話しかけてありがとうございました。"Thank you for meeting with me."

The "お" is called "bikago"美化語 which makes the verb 話しかける an honorific. And, once honorifics are involved, then first and second person in a sentence usually can become implied. The implied first person is usually the listener. The speaker is usually the implied second person. With this honorific "with me" is implied.

スクシュールを添削できてありがとうございました。"Thank you for updating / correcting the schedule."

Comment: Let me correct your Japanese. 1) ×なさっていただき → ◎していただき(orしてくださり, していただきまして, してくださいまして)　2) ×つつしんで誠にありがとうございました。→ (if you need to use つつしんで) ◎つつしんでお礼申し上げます。　3) ×お話しかけてありがとうございました。→ 〇お話させていただきありがとうございました。 ◎お時間をいただきありがとうございました。（btw, 話しかけてくださりありがとうございました would mean "Thank you for talking to me (in the sense of 'starting a conversation with me')."　4) ×スクシュールを添削できて → スケジュールを調整/変更してくださり/いただき...